# Rearranging the order of months in a rose plot to appear chronologically

Tags: r, ggplot2, visualization

I am having difficulty trying the rearrange the order of the months around my rose plot so that they appear in chronological order (Jan - Dec).

My data are organised in chronological order and are each assigned a group, which represents the season (D: Winter, A: Spring, B: Summer, C: Autumn).

```
head(Data)

  group  variable     value
1     D Janurary   6.896953
2     D Janurary   2.858804
3     D Janurary   7.197239
4     D Janurary   4.475334
5     D Janurary  11.957710
6     D Janurary  12.339196
```

I am using ggplot2 to plot my rose plot:

```
ggplot(data=Data,aes(x=variable,y=group,fill=value))+
  geom_tile(colour="black",size=0.1)+
  scale_fill_gradientn(colours=c("lightblue","darkblue"))+
  coord_polar()+xlab("")+ylab("") + theme_minimal()
```

Any ideas? All help is very much appreciated!
[image: image description]

Comment: I worked it out: Data$Month <- factor(Data$Month, levels=c('January', 'Feburary', 'March', 'April', 'May', 
                                          'June','July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 
                                          'November', 'December'))